# JSON rearrangement

Tags: javascript

I have following object which I want to rearrange so I can pass to a template. Need help for converting it from following format

```
var nature = [
  {
    "type": "fruit",
    "name": "apple",
    "color": "red",
  },
  {
    "type": "vegetable",
    "name": "carrot",
    "color": "orange",
  },
  {
    "type": "fruit",
    "name": "grape",
    "color": "green",
  },
  {
    "type": "vegetable",
    "name": "tamato",
    "color": "red",
  },
];
```

to this format

```
var nature = [{
    "fruit": [
        {
            "type": "fruit",
            "name": "apple",
            "color": "red"
        },
        {
            "type": "fruit",
            "name": "grape",
            "color": "green"
        }
    ],
    "vegetable": [
        {
            "type": "vegetable",
            "name": "carrot",
            "color": "orange"
        },
        {
            "type": "vegetable",
            "name": "tomato",
            "color": "red"
        }
    ]
}];
```

Looking for quickest way of achieving it. Thanks for looking at the post. Appreciate the help.

Comment: What have you tried? Generally some sort of looping structure would be advisable.

Comment: This is not JSON. It's a JavaScript object.

Comment: well, it looks like you'd iterate over the object, placing each element in the appropriate array, based on type. have you actually tried implementing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fight nature!**

```
var goAgainstNature = function(oldNat) {
    var newNat = {}, i;

    for(i = 0; i < oldNat.length; i++) {
        (newNat[oldNat.type] = (newNat[oldNat.type] || [])).push(oldNat[i]);
    }

    return [newNat];
};
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will be right

```
var goAgainstNature = function(oldNat) {
    var newNat = {}, i;

    for(i = 0; i < oldNat.length; i++) {
        (newNat["'"+oldNat[i].type+"'"] = (newNat[oldNat.type] || [])).push(oldNat[i]);
    }

    return [newNat];
};
```